# How to solve problems while installing ui in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-ui

While installing laravel/ui I got this following error.

```
Using version ^2.0 for laravel/ui

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v6.18.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.0
    - laravel/ui 2.x-dev requires illuminate/support ^7.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[7.x-dev], illuminate/support[7.x-dev, v7.0.0, v7.0.1].
    - laravel/ui v2.0.0 requires illuminate/support ^7.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[7.x-dev], illuminate/support[7.x-dev, v7.0.0, v7.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[7.x-dev, v6.18.0].
    - don't install illuminate/support 7.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.1|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.0
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v6.18.0, required as ^6.2) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v6.18.0].
    - Installation request for laravel/ui ^2.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/ui[2.x-dev, v2.0.0].
```

I'm using laravel version 6.18. How to solve this problem?

Comment: For laravel 6.x follow this link, for **laravel/ui** version https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/frontend#introduction

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Laravel ui has been released alongside Laravel 7 about an hour ago and Laravel ui 2.0 depends on Laravel 7.

Either upgrade your project to Laravel 7 or install Laravel ui 1.x instead.

Answer (score 14):

Try this:
it's working for my laravel 6.2

`composer require laravel/ui "^1.2"`

Answer (score 9):

For laravel 6x:

> composer require laravel/ui "^1.2"

For laravel 7x:

> composer require laravel/ui "^2.0"

For laravel 8x:

> composer require laravel/ui "^3.0"

For laravel 9x:

> composer require laravel/ui "^4.0"

Answer (score 7):

if you are using laravel 6, then try this command

`composer require laravel/ui "^1.0" --dev -vvv`

Are you trying to upgrade to laravel 7?

If that is the case you have to be doing something wrong I just updated as I said with no problems.

You have to update laravel first not the framework.

Only run `composer update` for framework after laravel is updated.

If you don't do this correctly you will always get errors.

Also, run `composer clearcache`

`composer selfupdate`

`composer dumpautoload`

If needed.

Also sometimes it helps to delete vendor and rerun composer install.

Answer (score 1):

According to Laravel framework documentation use this command

****Laravel 8.* in requires laravel/ui version 3.4****

```
composer require laravel/ui:^3.4
```

**Laravel 7. in requires laravel/ui version 2.4**

```
composer require laravel/ui:^2.4
```

****Laravel 6.* in requires specific laravel/ui version 1.0****

```
composer require laravel/ui:^1.0 --dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Run for current available  version

```
 composer require laravel/ui
```

Answer (score -1):

For people trying to upgrade from laravel version from 6.18 to 7 and changing the composer.json file as per https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade#updating-dependencies gives the below error :
- conflic issue
- laravel/ui[v1.1.0, ..., 1.x-dev] require illuminate/support ~5.8|^6.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.8.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev, v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev].

Solution :

1. Before changing the composer.json, remove laravel/ui - `composer remove laravel/ui`
2. Add `"laravel/ui": "^2.0"` in composer.json with other dependencies mentioned in the official document and run `composer update`