# Laravel 7X admin/login loops back to admin/login despite correct credentials

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, phpmyadmin, admin

[image]I am working on a Laravel admin panel that loops back to admin panel when i input the crenditials. The goal is to navigate to th edashboard. Laravel vrsion is 7x. I am working on it from the localhost/xampp. I double checked the database connection in the relevant files, **env**, **database.db**.  it marches the database in phpmyadmn. Thank you in advance for the suggestions

**N/B** It has no error to trace

**routes/admin.php**

```
<?php
Route::group(['prefix'  =>  'admin'], function () {

    Route::get('login', 'Admin\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('admin.login');
    Route::post('login', 'Admin\LoginController@login')->name('admin.login.post');
    Route::get('logout', 'Admin\LoginController@logout')->name('admin.logout');

    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:admin']], function () {

    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('admin.dashboard.index');
    })->name('admin.dashboard');

});
});
```

**app\Http\Controllers\Admin\LoginContoller.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Auth;


class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect admins after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/admin';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest:admin')->except('logout');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('admin.auth.login');
    }

    /**
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
 */
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email'   => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|min:6'
    ]);
    if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt([
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => $request->password
    ], $request->get('remember'))) {
        return redirect()->intended(route('admin.dashboard'));
    }
    return back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));

}

/**
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
 */

public function logout(Request $request)
{
    Auth::guard('admin')->logout();
    $request->session()->invalidate();
    return redirect()->route('admin.login');
}
}
```

**app\Exceptions\Handler.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

Use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Throwable;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * A list of the exception types that are not reported.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * A list of the inputs that are never flashed for validation exceptions.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontFlash = [
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
    ];

    /**
     * Report or log an exception.
     *
     * @param  \Throwable  $exception
     * @return void
     *
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function report(Throwable $exception)
    {
        parent::report($exception);
    }

    /**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Throwable  $exception
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     *
     * @throws \Throwable
     */
    public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
    {
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }

    /**
 * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
 * @param AuthenticationException $exception
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
    protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json(['message' => $exception->getMessage()], 401);
        }
        $guard = Arr::get($exception->guards(), 0);
        switch($guard){
            case 'admin':
            $login = 'admin.login';
            break;
            default:
            $login = 'login';
            break;
        }
        return redirect()->guest(route($login));
    }
}
```

**app\Http\Middleware\RedirectAuthenticated.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
   /**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @param  string|null  $guard
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    switch($guard){
        case 'admin':
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                return redirect('/admin');
            }
            break;
        default:
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                return redirect('/');
            }
            break;
    }
    return $next($request);
}
}
```

**routes/web.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
require 'admin.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| 
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});


Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

.env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=sarliam-shop
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=''
```

database.php

```
 'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'sarliam-shop'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

Comment: `RedirectIfAuthenticated` is typically used for "guest" routes so that you get redirected to a home page if authenticated instead of having to authenticate: `Route::get('/login',  'HomeController@login')->middleware('guest:web');`.  Do you have a route using this middleware?

Comment: Hello @adam yes adam i have .`public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    switch($guard){
        case 'admin':
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                return redirect('/admin');
            }
            break;
        default:
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                return redirect('/');
            }
            break;
    }
    return $next($request);
}` is that it or maybe i have not undertood your question

Comment: I don't see a guest route defined in your question `roots/admin.php`.

Comment: Hello @adam , Kindly check `routes/web.php` i have included it in the question. Is that what you mean. If not how would you have gone about it?

Comment: Try a `dd` on your login success before `return redirect()->intended(route('admin.dashboard'));` so that you are sure you are entering the correct route.

Comment: What is inside `routes/admin.php`

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi the error still persits.. It still loops back to  admin login

Comment: Does it loop back to `admin/login` or `login`?  Did you try checking the query if it's having the correct parameters? Because I have reproduced your code with seeding an admin and it works fine.

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi it loops back to `admin/login`. Yes, I have checked the query. I have attached a screenshot of the same maybe I have missed something. I have also added `.env` file and `database.php` kindly check.. thank you

Comment: Can you post the query. Also see the `password` column having value: it shows non-hashed/ plain value. But when we call the attempt method it usually crypts the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out your problem lies in the `password` column as it does not have a hashed value:

A hashed value appears to be somewhat like this:`$2y$10$ZQcgqgmFuqwQcZW7GYQsR.KmGxmw6mXDCwyKRHksw039IhU34A49W`

[image]

**Solution:**

Check the method you are using to register admin. Be it seeder or any other procedure, verify if it has the following method called to hash the **password** string

```
 Hash::make($data['password'])
```

Thus when this section executes:

```
   Auth::guard('admin')->attempt([
    'email' => $request->email,
    'password' => $request->password]);
```

> > The user will be retrieved by the value of the email column. If the user is found, the hashed password stored in the database will be compared with the password value passed to the method via the array.

For more details please have a look: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#included-authenticating

I hope this helps. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know why this is happening exactly but i think laravel is confused due to a problem in using the admin.php routes so ,

i suggest you take this part of code

```
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:admin']], function () {

    Route::get('/admin', function () {
        return view('admin.dashboard.index');
    })->name('admin.dashboard');

});
```

and put it in `web.php` and delete it from `routes/admin.php`
note that i added `'/admin`' to the code so that every thing pointing to /admin will work just fine 
hope this help if it didn't work please keep me posted

Comment: Unfortunately the error persists. I have  tried commenting  out  that particular code in ```admin.php```, but it still loops.  more suggestions are welcomed and thank you @RYOK